# What is the API to get list of all projects from Podio?

Tags: php, api, podio

I need assistance getting API, using which I can fetch all projects created in my Podio account.

I want to get the JSON feed from it and display it on my website for a different purpose. I went through their document, but I found APIs oriented around tasks, but not specific to getting project names. Am I missing anything?

Please let me know if anyone has done something similar in past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have an app in Podio that you've named "Projects". To fetch all items in that app you need to use [Filter items](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747) with your app id as the parameter. You find the app id in the item modal under Actions->Developer Info

[image: Screenshot]